# AFNetworking and Expecta

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to run a project with AFNetworking and I am getting the error

```
Expecta.h file not found
```

Expecta.h is included in AFNetworkingTests.h, a file from the AFNetworking project which I have not touched.
I dont know if I should import [Expecta from its Github](https://github.com/petejkim/expecta) or if I'm doing something wrong. I haven't found any tutorial of AFNetworking that mentions I should import that project so thats why it raised some doubts on how I should fix this problem.

(I had a similar problem with another file and the solution was to add some `Framework Search Paths` so thats why I'm asking, maybe I should do something like that here as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to run an AFNetworking test target, you will need to run `$ pod install` in the Tests directory (assuming that you have CocoaPods installed).

Otherwise, if you're including AFNetworking as a dependency for another project, you should only include the `AFNetworking` subdirectory at the root of the project, rather than the other files and folders.

That said, the recommended way to include it is CocoaPods (adding `pod 'AFNetworking'` to your `Podfile`), so you should consider doing that.

Comment: The AFNetworking repository includes subdirectories for Example and Tests, which include their own targets and dependencies. Adding those into your project will cause linking issues.